# Proving sibling relationship

Tags: visa-refusals, paperwork, sweden, family

My sister's Swedish Visa was refused. My elder brother is a Swedish citizen and wanted to sponsor her, but the embassy said there is no proof that they are siblings, despite the fact that they bear the same surname. My question is how can she prove they are siblings?

Comment: You go to get documents that show they have the same parents.

Comment: In Sweden, you order a *personbevis 120* (requesting all family relations to be displayed). In your country you get a birth certificate

Comment: There are tens of millions of people around the world with the surnames Wang or Devi. There are thousands with the last name Andersson in Sweden - why would anybody accept the claim they were siblings on that basis alone?

Comment: The relevant authority to contact regarding proving Swedish citizenship would be Skatteverket ("The Ministry of Taxation"), see [this](https://www.skatteverket.se/servicelankar/otherlanguages/inenglish/individualsandemployees/livinginsweden.4.7be5268414bea064694c3f8.html). The population registration certificate would be how a Swedish citizen can prove their identity when applying for an ID card or passport. Depending on what information that document contains, it may work as proof. I'd contact Skatteverket and ask them how to proceed.

Answer (score 26):

You would typically prove that with some sort of birth certificate or a similar document stating that you have the same parent(s), i.e. that your father and/or your mother have the same name, date and place of birth. Obviously, you would have to provide a birth certificate for the sponsor and another one for the applicant. In some countries, it's also possible to submit a copy of a [family register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_register) that would document your relationship even more directly.

Comment: and I suppose that both documents should have a unique ID to identify the specific person, usually this would be the equivalent to a national ID number

Comment: @Rsf No, not necessarily, many countries do not have any system like that or only created it recently or limit it to specific purposes (say tax and insurances). That's typically why the date and place of birth of the parents are included.

Comment: So aren't we back to to square one ? what if the parents have a common name as well ?

Comment: @Rsf Not exactly, as I just wrote, you rely on the date and place of birth of the parents (there is a reason I keep mentioning this). You also have the first/middle/personal names on top of any last name (which parents and children might not even share or doesn't exist in some cultures). It's one thing to have many “Nielsen” or “Nguyen” in the world, it's a lot less likely to have two distinct Connie Inge-Lise Nielsen born in place X on date Y. It's not theoretically impossible but that's how it works anyway.